# Filtering a drop down list values in liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet

I'm developing a liferay portlet and I'm new to it. In one of my forms I have two drop down lists. I want the second drop down list values be filtered when user selects a value in the first one. For example if the user selects a department in the first drop down list, the second on shows the employees of the selected department. I don't have any Idea how to do this in liferay. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using AJAX. Normally you can use jQuery, but liferay has a framework for that called Alloy UI. The idea is that when the user selects something in the first drop down, the application sends the selected row to the portlet and this sends back the new list for the second drop down.

Comment: As a note, you can use jQuery and most other JavaScript libraries with Liferay (http://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/using-jquery-or-any-javascript-library-in-liferay-6-0).